# React Deck.gl IconLayer Right Click

Tags: reactjs, deck.gl, google-maps-react

I have been trying to figure out how to get right click to work on IconLayer map marker.  I have tried the suggested way

eg.

```
onClick: (info, event) => console.log(event.rightcllick)
```

but this does not seem to be working for me.  Whenever I right-click no event is fired or my action listener fires from the map canvas instead (I have already tested removing the map listener I get the same results, no event)

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

**Quick update on this...**

after some further searching, I have found this in the docs.

https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/interactivity#calling-the-picking-engine-directly

however, when I fire the onclick i am unable to find any markers on the map and the `pickInfo` comes back as null.

I have had to slightly adapt the way it has been done as this is a class based components so I am unable to use hooks

```js
    ...

    deckRef = React.createRef()

    deckClick = e => {
        const pickInfo = this.deckRef.current.pickObject({
            x: e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY,
            radius: 1,
            layerIds: ['icon-layer-TEST'],
        })

        console.log(pickInfo)
        console.log(e, e.clientX, e.clientY)
        console.log(this.deckRef.current)
    }


    render() {
        const { center, google, initialMapCenter, language, zoom } = this.props

        return (
            <Container
                className={MAP_CONTAINER_CLASS_NAME}
                id="map"
                onContextMenu={this.deckClick}
            >
                <DeckGL ref={this.deckRef}>
                    <GoogleMap

    ...
```

Comment: Try to look into the Definition of the component, it may provide the idea of how and where to use the click event.

Comment: After reading the docs, it looks like you can add a ref to deckGl, then place an `oncontextmenu` handler on a parent div, and use the `pickingObject` to find the closest marker.

Im just working the solution through now and will post if this works

Comment: Any updates regarding that?